# JavaScript Map shadowing

Tags: javascript, dictionary, lexical-scope

Writing a parser in JavaScript, for any language, one obviously uses Map to store mappings of names to variables.

Most languages allow in some way or another variable in an inner scope to shadow one in an outer scope. The ideal data structure to implement this is a functional map. In the absence of that, there would seem to be two alternatives.

1. Treat Map as though it were a functional map, create a copy of the outer map, add the inner variable to the copy, let it be garbage collected when the inner scope ends. This is elegant, but spends O(N) time copying existing variables each time, so might be slow if there are many variables live at a given point.
2. Go full imperative style, just use a single map, save the old binding and restore it at the end of the inner scope. This is fast, but inelegant and error-prone.

Is there a better option I'm missing? Is there a consensus on which option is best?

Comment: "*one obviously uses Map to store mappings of names to variables.*" - why?

Comment: Are you writing a parser or an interpreter? The parser should not need to store actual variables.

Comment: @Bergi Well, right now I'm writing a parser for the TPTP file format, which does indeed need to store actual variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a linked list of `Map` objects to represent the scope *chain*. If the identifier is not found in the first link, recursively traverse the rest until the global scope.

Comment: Right, that is an option; it amounts to creating a simple functional map class with linear time lookup, which again has the potential to be slow if there are many variables.

Comment: Yes, it basically is that. However it does cope better than linear with scopes with many variables and the number of chain links is usually bounded, as one does not nest (scope) blocks indefinitely in well written programs. So overall I'd still expect `O(1)` access.

Comment: And just in case, if you need better performance, you can relatively easily optimise this by migrating the lookup results (assuming the scopes are static and you store variable references not values in the maps) down in the chain when they are accessed but missed (i.e. copy the entries lazily), while keeping your data structure transparent.

Comment: Right. I ended up putting a straightforward version into a package with a few other general utility functions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iop